# See service hostname from OpenShift CLI

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

In OpenShift Container Platform v3.11 I can able to see the service hostname from the web console interface by inspecting the service.

In the web console if going to Applications > Services > service-name > Details.

You see the following info:

Selectors: app=nexus3, deploymentconfig=nexus3
Type: ClusterIP
IP: 172.30.154.6
Hostname: **nexus3.xm-nexus.svc**
Session affinity: None

Is there a way to see the service hostname from the CLI using the `oc` tool? I haven't been able to find it from reading the docs or online.

Example Hostname: **nexus3.xm-nexus.svc**

If you issue a `oc get svc` you will see the following but not the hostname.

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
nexus        ClusterIP   172.30.186.244   <none>        3000/TCP   2h
```

Answer (score 5):

Not directly. The hostname doesn't exist on the service object itself so you won't see it via the cli. However it is just a concatenation of `(service-name).(service-namespace).svc`. [See docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) on DNS for services

You could template it out via the cli if desired.

`oc get svc nexus -o go-template --template='{{.metadata.name}}.{{.metadata.namespace}}.svc{{println}}'`

Comment: Okay, yes that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Use oc describe service  -n

e.g. oc describe service nexus3 -n

Services are provisioned labels like DNS.

Comment: Not sure if this is for a different version, but this command doesn't run.

Answer (score -2):

I think the simplest way is

```
oc get routes
```

And get the hostname that you need to access by url

```
NAME          HOST/PORT                                     PATH      SERVICES      PORT      TERMINATION   WILDCARD
demowildfly   demowildfly-swarmdemo2.192.168.42.87.nip.io             demowildfly   8080                    None
```

Comment: @AlexMirkhaydarov  , look at how to watch the hostname and use the **oc get svc** command, **but he still ask about the hostname** , so, my solution give another point of view and shows the host.